# Offline Database C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, offline

I started working on a big software project at the moment and what I need first is a place, where I can save all my data. 
I´ll write the software in C# and I already looked around for an offline-database solution but I don´t know, what is the best for me. 
My software should access the data all time and it should not be on a server.

So does anybody have experience with offline-databases?

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by offline database? Do you mean a database that is on the same machine/device as your application?

Comment: Yes, that´s what I mean. I don´t want to have it on a server, I just want it local on my PC.

Comment: Store your data in a class, and when you save serialise it using JSON.net and save that to a file. then you'll be able to de-serialise that from JSON. You could also try binary serialisation. But from flicking between online-offline mode json might be the best.

Comment: This should be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility: [MS SQL CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) - Very similar to SQL Server Express but file based, no server installation needed...

Comment: CE would be appropriate only if OP is developing for a portable device (e.g. a smart phone).

Comment: Why do you think so? SQL CE can also be used for desktop or web development... I think it depends on many factors whether CE is 'appropriate' :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the term offline is a bit misleading - if what you mean is a local relational database of some sort - not hosted on some remote server.  It is available all the time to your application.

You have an awful lot of solutions here, I would look at SQL-Server Express or SQLite first.  Both are mature well proven products, used in millions of applications.  SQLite is a little more lightweight, but since you don't talk about performance issues, I would recommend that as it does not need a separate installation form your app.  There are a bunch of different SQLite wrapper libraries for C#.

There are other solutions MySQL and Postgresql - but from the C# world I would perhaps start looking at the first two before evaluating these.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same software that you would use on a server, only the server in this case is your local machine.

So, if you prefer SQL Server, then you can download and install [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) (if it wasn't pre-installed on your computer in the first place).

If you prefer MySQL, you can [download](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and install that as well.

A Google search should lead you to the download page of nearly any other database platform that you might want to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a windows machine, then you most likely already have SQL Server Express installed on your machine.  It's very full featured, but is definitely intended for offline use as you've described.

If you are in a mono C# environment, or you just want something simple to install as you'll be writing an installer for other machines, then I would recommend using [FireBird Embedded](http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/fbmetasecur-embedded.html) or [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  They are both embedded databases that store themselves into a file wherever you choose (SQLite can also do this completely in memory, but it dissappears between runs).

Answer (score 0):

Considering 'offline database' as 'local database', i recommend [Sql Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx). It's a fine and 'lightweight' DB, ideal for running on a developing machine.

On a side note, whichever persistence strategy you choose, keep a layer of abstraction over it, so you can always change your mind or your requirements in a simpler way.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all of you. I think I first look at SQLite because I´ve read most about it.

Comment: @user896692 SQLite is also a fine DB, but keep in mind it is a much simpler piece of software (ie no locking mechanisms)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that explains 'offline-databases': [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p1.html)

I had almost the same problem and i found this tutorial and it woked for me just perfect.